# Submit returns an empty on the same page in JQuery Post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create a post page with a JQuery post, but for some reason when I press the post button, it redirects me to the same page and does nothing. I have no idea what I am missing here.

All I want is that when it logs in, it takes me to another page as `logged-in.php`
Could you take a look.

### Page

```
<form class="form-2" action="./" method='post' autocomplete="off">
        <h1><span class="log-in" style="font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 25px;">Log in</span><span class="inner"></span></h1><br>
        <p class="float">
          <label for="username"> <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-user" style="font-size:15px;"></i>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username or email" id="email" >
        </p>
        <p class="float">
            <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock" style="font-size: 15px;"></i>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="showpassword" id="passwd"> 
        </p><br>
        <br>

        <p class="clearfix">    
            <div class="register">Don't have credentials? Please <a href="./register.php">Register</a>.
                <input type="submit" onclick="users_login();" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </div> 
        </p>       
    </form>
    <div class="_fields" align="left" id="login_status"></div><br clear="all">
```

### JS ( users_login() )

```
   function users_login() 
   {

var vpb_email = $("#email").val();
var vpb_passwd = $("#passwd").val();


if(vpb_email == "")
{
    $("#login_status").html('<div class="info">Please enter your account email address to proceed.</div>');
    $("#email").focus();
}
else if(vpb_passwd == "")
{
    $("#login_status").html('<div class="info">Please enter your account password to go.</div>');
    $("#passwd").focus();
}
else
{
    alert("Inside the Ajax Validator: " + vpb_email  + " Password " + vpb_passwd);
    var dataString = 'email=' + vpb_email + '&passwd=' + vpb_passwd + '&page=users_login';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save_details.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() 
        {

            $("#login_status").html('<br clear="all"><br clear="all"><div align="left"><font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color:black;">Please wait</font> <img src="images/loadings.gif" alt="Loading...." align="absmiddle" title="Loading...."/></div><br clear="all">');
        }, 
        complete: function(){ 

        },
        success: function(response)
        {

            var response_brought = response.indexOf('login_process_completed_successfully=yes');
            if (response_brought != -1) 
            {

                $("#login_status").html('');
                window.location.replace(response);
            }
            else
            {

                $("#login_status").fadeIn(1000).html(response);
            }
        }
    });
}
  }
```

### PHP (save_details.php)

```
$user_email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
        $user_password = trim(strip_tags($_POST['passwd']));
        $encrypted_md5_password = md5($user_password);

        $validate_user_information = mysql_query("select * from `signup_and_login_table` where `email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_email)."' and `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($encrypted_md5_password)."'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($validate_user_information) == 1)
        {
            $get_user_information = mysql_fetch_array($validate_user_information);
            $_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"] = $user_email;
            $_SESSION["USER_FULLNAME"] = strip_tags($get_user_information["firstname"].'&nbsp;'.$get_user_information["lastname"]);
            echo 'index.php?uid='.$_SESSION["USER_FULLNAME"].'&';
            echo 'login_process_completed_successfully=yes';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<br><div class="info">Sorry, you have provided incorrect information. Please enter correct user information to proceed. Thanks.</div><br>';
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to `return false;` at the end of your `users_login()` function to keep the form from actually submitting as normal.

Furthermore, if you have syntax errors in your JS, the form will just go ahead and submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press the submit button, the form is automatically submitted causing a reload of the page, as the page need to be reloaded to send the data - because of this, the javascript is not runned. To prevent this behavior, do the following:

```
<form class="form-2" action="./" method='post' autocomplete="off" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
```

This should help you.